# imports not used in while

Tags: python, while-loop, pycharm

I'm making a bot in python and it works normally, but I need a certain part of the code to be in an infinite loop, so when i put the code inside the "while True" it looks like my imports are unusable. can someone explain to me how i can solve this?´

```
import datetime
import os
import time
import cv2
import pytesseract
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

caminho = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
data = datetime.datetime.now()
h = data.strftime("%h")
d = data.strftime("%d")
H = data.strftime("%H")
M = data.strftime("%M")
S = data.strftime("%S")
hd = h + d
t = H + M
pasta =f"C:/Kprints/{hd}"
chave = "****"

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("*****")
    page.locator('xpath=/html/body/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[19]/button[1]').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    page.locator('xpath=/html/body/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/input').click()
    page.fill('xpath=/html/body/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/input', "****")
    page.locator('xpath=/html/body/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[6]/input').click()
    page.fill('xpath=/html/body/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[6]/input', "****")
    page.locator('xpath=/html/body/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/button').click()
    page.locator('xpath=/html/body/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/img[1]').click()
    page.locator('xpath=/html/body/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]').click()
    page.locator('xpath=/html/body/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/button').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
     page.screenshot(path=f"{pasta}/{t}.png")
    time.sleep(1)
img = cv2.imread(f"{pasta}/{t}.png")
time.sleep(1)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = caminho
texto = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
time.sleep(1)
if not os.path.isdir(pasta):
    os.mkdir(pasta)
list = os.listdir(pasta)
for arquivo in list:
    if chave not in texto:
        os.remove(f"{pasta}/{arquivo}")
```

```
 Errors:

Unused import statement 'import os'
Unused import statement'import cv2'
Unused import statement 'import pytesseract'
This code is unreachable
```

Answer (score 1):

Your analyzer is saying the code using them can't be reached because your `while` loop, being infinite, renders it impossible to reach any code after it. Either:

1. The loop never ends, or
2. The calls inside it raise an exception, that (thanks to no `try` blocks being involved) will bubble up (skipping the remaining code) and end the program.

Either way, as written, the code after the loop never runs, so those imports are *effectively* unused.

The question for you is: Do you expect/need the code after that loop to run? If so, the loop cannot be infinite and you need to change the code so it can end. If not, why is the code after the loop even there?

Comment: well, I'm still learning to code, but what I tried to do exactly, was to make the code repeat all the time starting from the first line after the while, until I break the code by closing the program manually

Comment: @alexStAcK: Okay, but when you close it, what happens with all the code after the loop? That's why you get the warning; all the code after the loop can't run, under any circumstances.

Comment: when I run the code it runs one as I programmed it but it seems that it runs only 1 time and then stands still as if it was "waiting for something", I believe that's what you just explained...  what would be the best way to solve this so that it can restart the loop using the imports?

Answer (score 0):

Those are not errors. Those should be just warnings.

Can you try re-run and post actual output here?

You code gets stuck in that loop so imports not used and yes pytesseract can not be reached.

Practice this code snippet first:

```
key = ""
while key != "q":
    key = input("Enter a Key: ")
    if key == "q":
        break
    print(f"You Entered: {key}")
```

Comment: when I run the code it enters the loop that I programmed, so there is no output that I can post here... Except for the interruption message when I stop it manually, do you want to check this message?

Comment: It seems like you do not quite understand what you are doing. Simply place a key to exit loop. Then you will get rid of  those warnings.

See above code snippet. I hope it helps :)

Comment: I really don't understand very well, I'm learning now so it's all very confusing for me, thanks for the help, I'll try to do what you said 